# Major GC decreasing performance

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, memory, garbage-collection

We are having frecuent outages in our app, basically the heap grows over time to the point were the GC takes a lot of CPU time and execute for **several minutes**, decreasing the app perfomance drastically. The app is in JSF with a tomcat server.

In the mean time, we:

- Increased the heap size from 15G to 26G (-Xms27917287424  -Xmx27917287424)
- Take several heap dumps (we are trying to determine the problem using these)
- Activated GC logs

With the heap size increase, GC is not executing for that much time but still takes a lot of CPU and frezees the app.
[image: spike]

So the question is:

- Is this normal? When the GC executes it frees memory, so i think this probably isn't a memory leak (Am I right?)
- Is there a way of optimize the GC or maybe this behavior is just a sympthom of something wrong in the app itself?
- How can I monitor and analyze this without taking a heap dump?

**UPDATE:**
I changed JSF from 2.2 to 2.3 because some heap dumps were pointing that JSF was using a lot of memory.
That didn't work out, and yesterday we had and outage again, but this time a little different (from my point of view). Also this time, we had to reset tomcat because the app didn't work anymore after a while

[image]

In this case, the garbage collector is running when de old gen heap is not full, and the new generation GC is running all the time.
¿What can be the cause of this?

Comment: The point of a GC is to simulate infinite memory, so it doesn't actually need to run until the heap can no longer be expanded.  Collecting garbage (at home or in the JVM) can either be done a little at a time, or in infrequent big huge bursts of activity during which everything else is blocked.  Sounds like you want to go for 'a little at a time' -- i.e., run the GC more often. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-collector-implementation.html#GUID-C2CA24AD-DC01-4B31-A868-F7DAC7E3BF4D) is a link some GC documentation.

Comment: your application looks pretty healthy, to me. where do you see that it takes a lot of cpu, though?

Comment: You most likely have a memory leak. A good profiler will help you finding it.

Comment: @Eugene Actually none of those charts show overall cpu, but you can see a spike on the app response time when the GC is running.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm using yourkit profiler and MAT, the only thing i could find is that JSF is storing a lot of stuff on session, thats where the memory allocation get pretty high. Although, when the GC runs, most of the memory is released.

Comment: @iggy so you don't think this can be a memory leak?
Also, can running the GC more often affect my app performance?

Comment: The spike in GC activity is just 4% of the CPU. The spike in the response time is bad, but you’re using one of the oldest GC algorithms the HotSpot JVM has to offer, with a full stop-the-world phase. Just switching to a concurrent garbage collector could eliminate the latency problem.

Comment: Well, I'm of the fundamentalist opinion that you can't have a "leak" in a language with a GC, since if it's reachable from the program it's  not leaked, and if it's not reachable, it can be collected. But what you can have is accumulating ever greater amounts of data that you don't intend to. But quibbling aside, in crude terms it takes *X* cpu-seconds to collect a certain amount of garbage.  At present you're paying *X* all at once. You can tune instead to spread the payments over time, thus make it less noticeable. That is often the right fix for huge latency spikes.

Comment: @iggy actually, the costs of garbage collection scale with the amount of still reachable objects. This can be seen in this chart perfectly. The spike in CPU consumption is right the moment where the gc can not reclaim as much as the other gc runs, so the “used” graph does not go down as usual, but up again and consistently, the survivor space has a peek too. But there is no leak, as the next gc run reclaimed all of that memory and you’re correct, as I also said, using the right tuning, i.e. a concurrent collector, can avoid such spikes.

Comment: Visualvm can attach to a running JVM. That may be a good alternative to heap dumps.

Comment: @iggy Can concurrent garbage collector be a problem in terms of the app performance? Also I see that there is a peak on the survivor space, can this indicate that we are creating a large number of objects on a certain point of time, "overflowing" the eden and survivor ?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen thanks a lot, I will try that. Does visualvm has a high overhead?

Comment: Since the number of requests processed at a time is not constant, the exact overlapping of processed requests and garbage collection can change arbitrarily and stay at a low average most of the time and then, suddenly have such a spike that indicates a large number of currently processed request that can not give up that memory. Like waves on the ocean which can suddenly form a single [monster wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_wave) out of nothing. A concurrent collector may degrade the performance *slightly* but eliminate the peaks. The best you can do is try and measure.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said in the comments, the behaviour of the application does not look unreasonable.  Your code is continually allocating objects that leads to heap space filling up, causing the GC to run.  There does not appear to be a memory leak since GC reclaims a lot of space and the overall used space is not continually increasing.

What does appear to be an issue is that a significant number of objects are being promoted to the old-gen before being collected.  Major GC cycles are more expensive in terms of CPU due to the relocation and remapping of objects (assuming you're using a compacting algorithm).

To reduce this, you could try increasing the size of the young generation.  This will have happened when you increased the overall heap size but not by enough.  Ideally, you want the majority of objects to be collected during a minor GC cycle since this is effectively free (the GC does nothing to the objects in Eden space as they are collected).  You can do this with the `-XX:NewRatio=` or `-XX:NewSize=` flags.  You could also try changing the survivor space sizes, again to increase the number of objects collected before tenuring. (use the `-XX:SurvivorRatio=` flag for this).

For monitoring, I find Flight Recorder and Mission Control very useful as you can drill down into details of how many objects of specific types are allocated.  It's also easy to connect to a running JVM or take dumps for later analysis.

Comment: Right now -XX:NewRatio is 3, for what I see on the graph, the app is not using all of the eden space. Is that correct? If it is correct, why would I increase the eden space?

Comment: It's not easy to tell from just these graphs. The fact that the old-gen repeatedly fills up and gets collected would indicate that during minor GCs objects are being promoted. The only way this could happen without minor GC is if almost all objects were being allocated directly in the old-gen because of size. GC log files would be needed for a better analysis.